# How to populate values in ms word using php

Tags: php, html

I want to display values from html to MS Word.I heard that PhpDocx is a good tool to generate the MS word document dynamically.But this tool is licenced.So i cant able to get it.when I tried using COM, the server is getting slow.How to generate MS word document from html form without using any componenet?

Comment: you've forgot a lot of information: which platform do you use? which php version? which format of document do you want to create?
Please improve your question

Comment: Finally i found solution for populating values from Webpages to Ms Word.Use plugin Called Open TBS to populate values ...See this tutorial           http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php?doc....

Answer (score 1):

Best Alternative is **PHPWord**.

To know more about its implementation and downloads, visit
[PHPWord - Documentation](http://phpword.codeplex.com/documentation)